# HTML , CSS , Dropdown Arrow , Select

Tags: html, css, select

I have created fiddle here, which shows select and dropdown arrow.

My problem is that the arrow is created using CSS and positioned on top of select.
however click on arrow doesn't open dropdown.

1. is there a way to use that css as background of select like we do when we use image arrow.
2. or is it possible to simulate the behavior on arrow click?

```css
.selectClass {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    width: 100px;
    background: #EEE;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.dropDownArrow {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 75px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<select class="selectClass">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
</select>
<div class="dropDownArrow"></div>
```

Comment: > https://jsfiddle.net/sumant/tme6yyqq/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the simplest solution here would be to ignore the mouse clicks on the arrow and let the clicks "go through" by using `pointer-events: none;`. That's the only needed change to your code, see it here:

```css
.selectClass {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  background: #EEE;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.dropDownArrow {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<select class="selectClass">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
</select>
<div class="dropDownArrow"></div>
```

Comment: @PaulSmith, thank you! I really think it's time to let the old IE versions die, especially with the auto-updated they have... OP: I'm afraid there is no alternative to this rule, but there are other outside the box solutions, such as using the arrow as the select background image.

Comment: http://glennnaessens.com/pointer-events-none-in-ie/     couldn't get the idea completely. @PaulSmith did you try above code on IE? < I don't have access to it.>

Comment: yes, it won't work for IE  8, 9, and 10, and my concern is that they're still 30% of market share (netmarketshare.com)

Comment: That's a pretty big number, didn't expect it.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a parent div around both elements with the background color, move the dropdown arrow behind the select header, make that header background transparent.  That way you see the arrow but, are only clicking on the select element box on top:

```css
.dropDownArrow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 75px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #555;
}
.selectClass {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
.dropdownWrapper {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdownWrapper">
  <div class="dropDownArrow"></div>
  <select class="selectClass">
      <option>One</option>
      <option>Two</option>
      <option>Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```